# How to publish a list of strings (of slash seperated values) to Amazon S3 as CSV?

Tags: java, csv, amazon-s3

I have a list of Strings as follows->

```
List<String> x=new ArrayList<String>();
Each string inside the list is of the following format -(They are slash separated)
String 1-Name/City/Age/Hobbie
String 2-Ross/Sydney/35/Painting
String 3-Joey/Wellington/40/Dancing
and so on
```

How to publish these strings to a S3 Bucket as a csv file ?

There should be four columns in the sheet Name,City,Age,Hobbie

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create .csv file from your input data. You can do it by writing your own logic to separate string and then writing it to file with the help of `PrintWriter` class of `java.io` package or you can you third party library which makes your life easy. Here is the list of libraries you can use.

- Apache Commons CSV: Apache's CSV offering for working with CSV Files
- Open CSV: Another popular and actively-maintained CSV library
- Flatpack: An open-source CSV library being actively developed
- CSVeed: Open-source and actively-maintained.

After the .csv file is created you can use aws sdk (`aws-java-sdk-s3`) to upload the file . Reference [link](https://stackabuse.com/aws-s3-with-java-uploading-files-creating-and-deleting-s3-buckets/) for S3 file upload